# How we take correct string from user in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

When taking "user name" from user as input using console app .. How can I make him input string not Enter key in keyboard as input string?**

when i want your name ,I want you not to enter spaces then enter key or enter key without writing your name

```
string name;
name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Here,I don't want user press Enter as input rather than his name

Comment: It is unclear whether you are using a console app or form app. But, my guess is that if the user name field is null, you can prompt the user to enter a valid user name. Perhaps you should edit your question with some sample codes that you had tried.

Comment: @Hari Console app

Comment: @AhmedElemam, handle that exception to prompt the user again for the username. You can also be clearer to the user that a username needs to be specified to move forward onto whatever the app does... some sample code posted here may make it helpful to understand what the overall picture of your problem is.

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: What do you want the user to press in order to signify that they're done entering the user name, if they can't press `[Enter]`?

Comment: @RufusL You don't understand me.. I don't want him to press Enter instead of writing word!!

Comment: So all blank spaces is ok, followed by Enter? What are the rules here...

Comment: what ever,I only want correct word from him

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Everyone is used to pressing `[ENTER]` to indicate *I am done entering the data*

Comment: @CodingYoshi Giving  example.. when i want your name ,I want you not to enter spaces then enter key or enter key without writing your name

Comment: Like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BlI5V4)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can apply the rules to the user name after they have entered it, which they signify by pressing `[Enter]`. At this point, you can validate the entry and, if it's incorrect, display a message to them indicating what needs to be changed, and prompt them again. This is all done in a loop, whose exit condition is a valid user name.

To simplify things, I've put this into a helper method that has some arguments that can be set to enforce some general rules. You can always add your own rules, too:

```
public static string GetStringFromUser(string prompt, int minLength,
    bool allowAlpha, bool allowNumeric, bool allowNonAlphaNumeric)
{
    var errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
    var input = string.Empty;

    while (true)
    {
        errorMessage.Clear();
        Console.Write(prompt);
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (input.Length < minLength)
        {
            errorMessage.AppendLine(
                $" - Entry must be longer than {minLength} characters");
        }
        if (!allowAlpha && input.Any(c => char.IsLetter(c)))
        {
            errorMessage.AppendLine(" - Entry must not contain any letters");
        }
        if (!allowNumeric && input.Any(c => char.IsDigit(c)))
        {
            errorMessage.AppendLine(" - Entry must not contain any numbers");
        }
        if (!allowNonAlphaNumeric && input.Any(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)))
        {
            errorMessage.AppendLine(
                " - Entry must not contain any non-alphanumeric characters");
        }

        if (errorMessage.Length == 0) break;

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe following errors must be corrected:");
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessage.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    return input;
}
```

Then, to use this function, you just pass in the rules you want to enforce. For instance, I am specifying below that the user name must be 6 characters and cannot contain any numeric or non-alphanumeric characters:

```
static void Main()
{
    var userName = GetStringFromUser("Enter your user name: ", 6, true, false, false);

    Console.WriteLine($"Welcome, {userName}!");

    Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Just passing by, liked the explanation with the code. +1